# ActionLink for Logout is rendering wrong route

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to figure out why my ActionLink renders wrong. In my _Layout.cshtml I have

```
<div class="col-sm-7">
    <ul>
        <li class="section-head section-head2 ">XYZ Technologies</li>
        <li>@ViewBag.Email</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5">
    @Html.ActionLink("Logout", "LogOut", "Submission", new {@class = "pull-right"})
</div>
```

But when I'm in a view on the 'customforms' controller it renders like this:

```
<div class="col-sm-7">
    <ul>
        <li class="section-head section-head2 ">XYZ Technologies</li>
        <li>someone@noserver.com</li>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-5">
    <a class="pull-right" href="/customforms/logout?Length=10">Logout</a>
</div>
```

I guess there's something overwriting it, but I'm not sure how to track down what. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Length=10 comes from an attempt to serialize a string object which is related to the "Submission" that has 10 characters. You can change it to

```
@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "LogOut", new { controller = "Submission" }, new {@class = "pull-right"})
```

In fact, "ActionLink" takes it as "routeValues" parameter.

Comment: i've never seen anyone use this override.. i guess i'll know what it's doing if i ever see it again.

Answer (score 0):

you're specifying route value in your actionlink helper..  to set the html attributes you need to add null for the route object param

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Logout", "LogOut", "Submission", null, new { @class = "pull-right" })
```